# signing up a Custom user model with CreateMixinModel

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I want to write an API for a Custom User Model with MiXin. I wrote a CustomUser which inherits Django User Model. Then I defined Student Profile with some attributes. in serilizer.py I defined the fields I want to get information from Users. Now in Views.py I don't know how to code to sign up user with CreateMixinModel

```
class StudentSignUpView(mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.CreateModelMixin, generics.GenericAPIView, ):
    """This part is relatng to sign up students a"""
    queryset = Student.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StudentSignUpSerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request,**kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.POST)
        print("answerrrrrr----------->>>", serializer)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            customusers = CustomUser.objects.all()
```

I want to be able a custom user to sign up

Comment: Won't `def post` is what you want?

Comment: yes I need def post

Comment: You will be doing `Signup` through `def post`.

Comment: can you please share the code of `CreateModelMixin`?

Comment: yes I want to signup through def post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use use generics `ListCreateAPIView` and you don't to write the get and post yourself.

All the user creation should be handled by the serializer.

It is not clear if `Student` is your custom user model or not. I assume it is.

So your view:

```
class StudentSignUpView( generics.ListCreateAPIView ):
    """This part is relatng to sign up students a"""
    queryset = Student.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StudentSignUpSerializer
```

Your serializer:

```
class StudentSignUpSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Student

        fields = ("username", "password")

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = Student.objects.create_user(username=validated_data["username"],
                                        password=validated_data["password"])

        return user
```

You can use your custom user model in your serializer and if you inherited from django's AbstractUser, you can use the `create_user` method to create the user and it also does some magic things ( look up the implementation).

If you need to do something else, like you mentioned, with some student profile, you can do it in the serializer after the user is created ( perhaps as one atomic transaction ).